# How can I pass cron and timezone dynamically. #Spring Scheduler

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

How can I pass cron and timezone dynamically in Spring Schedular

Comment: Have you tried before asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by passing corn expression from properties file

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
    public void methodServicesDemo()
    {
        System.out.println("Method execute  :: "+ new Date());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a TaskScheduler.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html